# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, intellij-idea

I trying to use hibernate as JPA implementation in my web application. I have spent several hours dealing with this problem. I have following directory structure http://i62.tinypic.com/345bqlt.png.

Here is content of my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myName" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxx"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxxxxxx"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am trying to access database from servlet

```
 EntityManager entityManager =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myName").createEntityManager();
        CustomerProvider customerProvider = new CustomerProvider(entityManager);
        Customer customer = customerProvider.get(9);
```

I am working in Intellij IDEA. I have previous simple Maven Hibernate project and it works, but in web app it doesn't seems to work.
I am getting such exception trying to access servlet.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myName
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    controller.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please !!! Help to solve this problem. I have to work, but cannot continue due this problem. Maybe it is incorrect to access database through dao in servlet, please suggest right way than.
You are my hope only.

Comment: do you have all hibernate jars in ur classpath, specially hibernate-entitymanager-XXX.jar

Comment: Yes surely , I have all jar in libs folder which in turn inside WEB INF

Comment: in image, folder name is MET-INF, it should be META-INF.

Comment: I have changed it, it is set in Module Settings, so it is doesn't matter. This didn't help (

Comment: please share dao implementation.